# How to quit a thrift server in Python

Tags: python, thrift

I am writing an application in Python that uses [thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) to communicate between itself and a client. Whenever I try to exit the application (using Ctrl-C or the exit button on the window), the thrift server keeps the application alive, probably because the server.serve() function enters an infinite loop. What is the best way to exit this server when the rest of the application quits?

Comment: Which type of thrift server are you using? Simple? Threaded?

Comment: I'm using a simple server, but I think it works the same either way.

Comment: Actually it doesn't. A simple server is a single threaded loop, a threaded server actually spins up new threads. When you press Ctrl+C only the main thread receives the signal, but python will wait for ALL threads before it exits.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my problem was not actually thrift-specific. I was running an infinite loop in a non-daemonic thread; therefore, python waited for that thread to close before my whole program would close. Setting "self.daemon = True" in the thread's **init** method fixed the problem nicely.